Freestyle line set is drawing things outside from the view
I'm working on an office scene  with Blender 4.1 and I have created a freestyle line set, but it is drawing things that are hidden by another object, here I leave You the render with and without the freestyle line:




Hello, AdverickMegrezWD, it certainly looks as though Freestyle has been unable to detect occlusion, here,  possibly due to floating-point resolution? I think it would help folks take a shot at answering if you could share a stripped-down version of your file showing the error on https://blend-exchange.com/ . Then we could try out our solutions before posting.

Uploaded the Blend file
